# Is there a standard for customer data?

Tags: oop

It seems like every time a new project gets started, a bunch of customer-related code gets copied and pasted.  First name, last name, gender, email, etc.

Is there a current standard for customer contact / id data?  It seems to me that it would be MUCH easier to have a defined standard for working with this information rather than getting stuck on whether or not to use "first_name" or "firstName" when creating this structure.

What I'm looking for is a universal format for a customer object.

Anyone seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

In java every variable name and also member variable names should be set in lower camel case. 
 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Here are the naming conventions from oracle: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

This is some kind of "standard" for such things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jan!

I think I should have been a bit more specific in what I was asking for.  I was wondering if there was some type of industry standard for a universal customer object.  Which fields should be included, how long they should be, etc.  Example - should a universal, standard customer object have the address info as part of the object or is there a standard for an address object?  I see a lot of disperate systems that all have a need to exchange some of this information and most orgs roll their own when it comes to customer metadata.

Comment: ah o.k, nice Idea. I will upvote your question to bring it more on top.

Answer (score 1):

A bit old, but have you looked at the Party Model as a standard way of dealing with things like customers?

Take a look at the data model diagrams from the Apache Open for Business Project - you'll find plenty of useful information on how to construct the customer object by looking at how they deal with the Party object first:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBTECH/Data+Model+Diagrams